# building an amazon store with drupal 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal-7

I've been playing around with an idea for an amazon store with Drupal 7. I do a lot of product reviews, and I typically link to amazon pages already (without referrer IDs, since I wanted toa void any questions of integrity all together), but having a seperate storefront link, well I'm playing with the idea.

I'm using Drupal 7, and I installed the Amazon API and Amazon Store module. It uses an Amazon AWS account and amazon associates ID. Basically creates a light storefront that does all the lifting through amazon itself. It only even uses Amazon items, which is fine since what isn't on Amazon, and only gives you a referral payout.

Well, what I'd love to do is have a stronger control over the items in the store. The Amazon Store module just gives you the option to control the basic items that are visible upon loading.

**What I'd like to do**: Create a store where categories match the contents of my site, and disable the search options. Is this possible with these modules? Does anyone have advice on creating something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the below module and I hope it will be handy

https://drupal.org/project/amazon_store

Comment: I've already got that one specifically, I'm just looking to see if I can get some deeper controls with it or not.

Comment: To add more deeper control you must need some custom work..:)